# Getting NDVI values into .csv format using Python

Tags: python, csv, ndvi

I have written the following code to get the NDVI values. I want this NDVI array in .csv format for data analysis.

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show

b4 = rasterio.open('C:\\Users\\ARSH\\Desktop\\LC08_L1TP_143051_20200120_20200120_01_RT.tar\\LC08_L1TP_143051_20200120_20200120_01_RT_B4.tif')
b5 = rasterio.open('C:\\Users\\ARSH\\Desktop\\LC08_L1TP_143051_20200120_20200120_01_RT.tar\\LC08_L1TP_143051_20200120_20200120_01_RT_B5.tif')
red = b4.read(1).astype('float64')
nir = b5.read(1).astype('float64')
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

check = np.logical_or ( red > 0, nir > 0 )
ndvi = np.where ( check,  (nir - red ) / ( nir + red ), -999 )
ndvi
```

I am getting the below result

[image]

I also tried using pyexcel

```
import pyexcel
pyexcel.save_as(array=ndvi,dest_file_name="C:\\Users\\ARSH\\Desktop\\ndvir.csv",dest_delimiter=':')
```

but my .csv file is not taking values in a single column. All values are coming in a row.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: I would recommend doing all of your analysis with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) rather than writing to csv and importing into Excel. Out of curiosity, what analysis are you doing in Excel once you import the NDVI values?

Comment: i want to find pearson's correlation between these NDVI values and climatic factors like temperature , humidity and precipitation. All the dataset of climatic factors are in csv format. I was not able to find a way so thought of taking ndvi values in csv and then finding the correlation.

Comment: is there any way of doing this using pandas with the ndvi array values and csv files?

Comment: look below my answer

Comment: This is how I would calculate pairwise Pearson's correlation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-corr/.

Answer (score 5):

There would be many was to do this, the method I use is to write my CSV file directly:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\ARSH\\Desktop\\ndvir.csv",'w') as WriteCSV:
    for ThisRow in array:
        WriteCSV.write(str(ThisRow)[1:-1] + '\n')
```

Using the with operator ensures the CSV file is closed at the end. `str(ThisRow)` returns `'[val,val...val]'` so using the string indexing `[1:-1]` which means everything but the first and last character then add a newline.

Comment: Maybe `csv_file` and `row` would be more pythonic names, I suggest... O;). Also, maybe `print(','.join(row), file=csv_file)` would also be more straightforward (but I think you'd need something like `numpy.set_printoptions(precision=20)`). Remember that [python rounds numbers when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142432/are-numpy-array-elements-rounded-automatically), whereas numpy `str()` provides scientific notation, which may or may not be what you need.

Comment: That is correct but ','.join will only work if row is a list of strings not numbers. Scientific notation can be a bit of a problem when reading the CSV file later so, as you say, it may not be what was wanted, if this is causing an issue a string can be built by iterating ThisRow which is float numbers and using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python ensure that no scientific notation exists - this could be done with list comprehension (for advanced users only) https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 4):

Using the script of [Intro to Python Gis: Raster calculations](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L6/raster-calculations.html) and the data from [EarthPy: vignette "earth-analytics"](https://earthpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
b4 = rasterio.open("/earth-analytics/data/vignette-landsat/LC08_L1TP_034032_20160621_20170221_01_T1_sr_band4_crop.tif")
b5= rasterio.open("/earth-analytics/data/vignette-landsat/LC08_L1TP_034032_20160621_20170221_01_T1_sr_band5_crop.tif")
red = b4.read(1).astype('float64')
red.shape
(1941, 2158)
nir = b5.read(1).astype('float64')
nir.shape
(1941, 2158)
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
{'divide': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore', 'invalid': 'warn'}
check = np.logical_or ( red > 0, nir > 0 )
ndvi = np.where ( check,  (nir - red ) / ( nir + red ), -999 )
ndvi.shape
(1941, 2158)
```

The result is a numpy array with 1941 rows and 2158 columns (as red and nir) and the first row has 2158 columns therefore it is normal that a csv file is not taking values in a single column  and all values are coming in a row.

If you want all the values into a simple column use [numpy ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)

```
ndvi.ravel().shape
(4188678,)
```

With [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) as Aaron recommends

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ndvi':ndvi.ravel()})
df.to_head() # 5 first values
       ndvi
0  0.511880
1  0.437500
2  0.310811
3  0.277589
4  0.329997
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Comment: How are you getting the exact NDVI values? when i tried the above coding using pandas i am getting the first 5 values same as in -999.0,-999.0...... Also in my excel sheet the only value is 999. I want the exact values of ndvi in my excel sheet. plss help

Comment: What is the result of   `ndvi.shape` ?

Comment: (7801, 7631)
this is the output of ndvi.shape

Comment: So there are 59529431 (7801x7631) nvdi values = `ndvi.ravel()`  (too big for Excel). What is the result of `ndvi.max()` and `ndvi.min()`(= -999.0)